# Add api routes to existing project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using **Rails 4.2.1** in the current project. I am using **devise** for authentication. Now I want to add api for mobile along with my all existing routes, for that I selected to use **devise_token_auth** gem. I have added a column tokens in User table to store the token and added in routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do
     mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: '/auth'
   end
end
```

added this line in **User.rb** in model

```
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

I have also created devise_token_auth folder in controllers folder and added files listed in here https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/tree/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth

Am I doing this right? can I use two authentication in one application?(for api and web)
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://zacstewart.com/2015/05/14/using-json-web-tokens-to-authenticate-javascript-front-ends-on-rails.html

Comment: I want to do it using devise_token_auth gem. Is it possible to add two authentication for web and mobile(using devise_token_auth)

Comment: Then goodluck, i had a lot of troubles with that gem actually. I prefer JWT for now.

Comment: can I use token validation using devise_token_auth and cookie authentication for web using devise?

Comment: I cant remember exactly, it should use. Play around, if dnt like it then use JTW, ez and fast.